# How can I copy Dll's to Program Files folder in Windows 2008 Server using C#

Tags: uac

We already have a C# application for Deploying Dll's to different environments(DEV/QA/PROD). This application when asked copies the required Dll's to Program Files folder. This was working fine in Windows 2003 server. But now we migrated our server environments to Windows Server 2008 which brings UAC into picture.

Now when we try to copy the Dll's from local desktop to Server Program files using our application the application is failing.

Can any one suggest me what is the C# code that can make my application to elevate it privileges which allows me to copy the Dll's to remote server.
Regards
Masthan

Comment: Exposing Server's Program Files is not preferred. Why dont you create a C# program with `XCOPY` utility & run in `Admin` mode. so you dont have any risks.

Comment: Instead of I running my program running under elevated mode (Run in Admin mode), how do I make my program directly run under Admin? The problem is I am launching my application using ClickOnce and it is NOT showing option to run under Admin mode.

Comment: I think you have to run in elevated mode, if you dont have `launching it in Admin mode`. As a matter of fact since its the copying of DLLs(which I assume as a single time task) its better to run the program itself in elevated mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an application assembly manifest that includes **requestedExecutionLevel** of **requireAdministrator**.

That way your **update** program will be run as an administrator.

You could also change your installer to give all users **Full Control** to your application folder; that way any user could modify your application.